# Building a Solution in Visual Studio 2017 Prompts me to Save .rptproj file"

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I'm using VS2017 Enterprise. My solution has a combination of Database Projects , SSRS projects and SSIS projects (all created in VS2015).

I've been able to upgrade the Reporting Services project. But when I try and build the solution I get prompted to save the .rptproj file. My solution can never build and deployed because I'm not able to save the file.

It was working fine in VS2015

**Error:**

> Parameter "unevaluatedValue" cannot be null

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate (e.g. error message) on "I'm not able to save the file"

Comment: The thing is I'm not sure  why I get prompted to save the .rptproj file at when I try to build the solution, If i unload the .rptproj the solution builds sucessfully

Comment: This is actually an issue of the software you are using and is off-topic here. Why not ask the question in the specific forum? See: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/121092/saving-updated-reporting-service-rptproj-throws-pa.html

Comment: I did, but have got no response. Is there a VS specific forum that i should be posting in (on this forum)